# Elasticsearch: Search fields containing arrays using arrays

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have an ES index where one of my mappings stores a simple array of named entities pre-set at the point of ingestion.

I'm trying to search my index using a given array of entities, to return documents where containing many of the same entities.

Some code for illustration...

```
GET /test_data/_search
{  
"query": {
    "match": {
      "entities": ['Trump', 'CNN', 'Oklahoma', 'Tiktok', 'Tulsa']
    }
  }
}
```

However, this returns a parse exception -- What would be the best method to search fields containing arrays using another array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for exact matches then change `match` to `terms` -- this functions as an OR query:

```
GET /test_data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "entities": [
        "Trump",
        "CNN",
        "Oklahoma",
        "Tiktok",
        "Tulsa"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

otherwise use a bool-should array of `match` queries:

```
GET /test_data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "entities": "Trump"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "entities": "CNN"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "entities": "Oklahoma"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can define how many of them should match with the [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#bool-min-should-match) param.